# how to integrate speech to text in react-native?

Tags: react-native, google-speech-to-text-api

Hi do anyone know how to integrate speech to text in react-native ?  I saw this package ( @react-native-community/voice) but it is not working for me. Is it possible to integrate google speech to text in react-native?

I just integrate @react-native-community/voice but it is not working for me. The app is crashed after manual linking. Is it possible to connect google speech to text? If yes, how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.